# Insert Multiple Rows with One insert statement and parameters

Tags: .net, vb.net, postgresql

I need to input multiple rows at once with one insert statement
from the data table into a database on PostgreSQL

```
insert into table1 values 
('1','aaa'),
('2','bbbb'),
('3','ccc')
```

this is my code to input multiple rows with one insert statement
and its works

```
Sub bandingkan_data_tblpibconr()
        Dim Bs_access As New DataTable
        Bs_access = query.LoadAcces_tblpibconr
        Dim dt3 As New DataTable
        dt3 = Bs_access
        Cmd.Connection = connNpgsql.OpenConnection()


        Dim kueri As String

        kueri = "insert into tblpibconr values"
        For i = 0 To dt3.Rows.Count - 1



            kueri = kueri + "('" + dt3.Rows(i)("car").ToString + "','" + dt3.Rows(i)("reskd").ToString + "','" + dt3.Rows(i)("contno").ToString + "','" + dt3.Rows(i)("contukur").ToString.Trim() + "','" + dt3.Rows(i)("conttipe").ToString + "')"
            kueri = kueri + ","

        Next
        kueri = kueri.Remove(kueri.Length - 1, 1)

        Cmd.CommandText = kueri
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


        connNpgsql.CloseConexion()
    End Sub
```

but I need to add these parameters on my code

```
          Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@car", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text).Value = dt3.Rows(i)("car").ToString
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reskd", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text).Value = dt3.Rows(i)("reskd").ToString
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contno", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text).Value = dt3.Rows(i)("contno").ToString
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contukur", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text).Value = dt3.Rows(i)("contukur").ToString.Trim()
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@conttipe", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text).Value = dt3.Rows(i)("conttipe").ToString
```

I don't know how to combine my parameters and my kueri variable

```
kueri = kueri + "('" + dt3.Rows(i)("car").ToString + "','" + dt3.Rows(i)("reskd").ToString + "','" + dt3.Rows(i)("contno").ToString + "','" + dt3.Rows(i)("contukur").ToString.Trim() + "','" + dt3.Rows(i)("conttipe").ToString + "')"
            kueri = kueri + ","
```

can anyone help me?

And if you know how to input data from the data table into the PostgreSQL database faster then this method using vb.net  please let me know.

Comment: Why are you creating three `DataTables` and only using one of them? The `New` keyword is used to create a new object so don't use it unless you actually want a new object. The first four lines of that method should be replaced with one: `Dim table As DataTable = query.LoadAcces_tblpibconr()`.

Comment: You conclude the wrong outcome in your requirement: It *is* possible to add multiple values w/ one roundtrip to the database without having the comma-separated syntax you provided. Just use the `DataAdapter` like @jmcilhinney demonstrated in his answer. If you don´t understand it, google it, there are a lot of tutorials about it and come back if you have a specific problem

Answer (score 1):

You don't loop through a `DataTable` to save data. You use a data adapter to save the lot in one go. I'll provide an example to demonstrate the principle and let you apply that principle to your specific scenario.

```vb
'Create and populate the DataTable.
Dim table As New DataTable

With table.Columns
    .Add("Name", GetType(String))
    .Add("Amount", GetType(Integer))
End With

With table.Rows
    .Add("One", 1)
    .Add("Two", 2)
    .Add("Three", 3)
End With

'Create the data adapter.
Using connection As New SqlConnection("connection string here"),
      command As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MyTable (Name, Amount) VALUES (@Name, @Amount)", connection),
      adapter As New SqlDataAdapter With {.InsertCommand = command}
    'Add parameters.
    With command.Parameters
        .Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Name")
        .Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Amount")
    End With

    'Save data.
    adapter.Update(table)
End Using
```

You need to make sure that the `RowState` of each `DataRow` is `Added` in order for them to be inserted. If you have added the rows in code, as I have above, then they already will be. If you're populating the `DataTable` with a data adapter then you can set its `AcceptChangesOnFill` property to `False` to leave the rows in that state. Otherwise, you can call `SetAdded` on each row.

You might check [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872) for more information.

Comment: hey sir can u explain more for me? because I don't think your code has the same method as mine what I need is to import multiple values with 1 execute sir. I'm sorry if I'm wrong 
 because I am new to this sir thanks...

Comment: A single `INSERT` command can only insert a single record. the way to insert multiple records is how I have deomstrated here. If you don't understand it then you don't understand the basics of ADO.NET, so you need to spend some time fixing that. This site is not for teaching you the basics. It is for help with specific issues, which I have provided. We should be able to assume that you either understand the fundamentals required to make use of the solution provided or will spend the time learning those fundamentals for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The `Using...End Using` block assures that your connection and command are closed and disposed even if there is an error. If possible always list your field names in your sql statement. I had to guess at the names.

Add the parameters once outside the loop. Then just reset the values of the parameters on each iteration.

```
Sub bandingkan_data_tblpibconr()
    Dim dt3 = query.LoadAcces_tblpibconr
    Using cn As New NpgsqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New NpgsqlCommand("insert into tblpibconr (Car, Reskd, Contno, Contukur, Conttipe) Values (@car, @reskd, @contno, @contukur, @conttipe);")
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@car", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text)
            .Add("@reskd", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text)
            .Add("@contno", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text)
            .Add("@contukur", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text)
            .Add("@conttipe", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text)
        End With
        cn.Open()
        For Each row As DataRow In dt3.Rows
            cmd.Parameters("@car").Value = row("car").ToString
            cmd.Parameters("@reskd").Value = row("reskd").ToString
            cmd.Parameters("@contno").Value = row("contno").ToString
            cmd.Parameters("@contukur").Value = row("contukur").ToString
            cmd.Parameters("@conttipe").Value = row("conttipe").ToString
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: sir, I  have tried ur code and it still needs looping the execute .is it possible to put the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()  outside the loop ? like my code above but with parameters

Comment: Mary I guess you habe a copy/paste error in your loop regarding parameter name `@car`

Comment: Additionally, that isn´t really what @Felix wanted. This solution fires one roundtrip to DB foreach row.

Comment: @AlexB. Thanks for noticing the paste error. There is a single connection - single trip to DB, the query is cached and the plan reused.

Comment: @Felix not sure if Bulk copy is available for postgresql. The solution provided by jmcilhinney has the single line of code but there is a loop of some sort hidden in the implementation.

Comment: @Mary, there's ALWAYS going to be a loop of some sort somewhere. Even if you use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` there's still going to be a loop performed by the database. It's simply not possible to do something repetitive without an effective loop at some level. Even if the OP could do what they suggested, i.e. an `INSERT` statement with multiple sets of values, there would still be a loop somewhere.

Comment: But if the loop is done on the database server or on the client is a huge difference

Comment: @AlexB. Not sure what you are referring to when you say "works that way" Here is an article on caching https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-sql-server-query-plan-cache/ My guess would be that `Insert Into...Select` runs the loop on the server as does a bulk copy. I agree that it would be faster.

Comment: @Mary I know the meaning of query plans, I referred to the part that every round trip from a client to the database consumes time and ressources (like Network I/O). So like you said  `Into...Select` or passing a table valued parameter should always be preferred when dealing with mass data.